# .Net application prompts sign in on the browser when debugging

Tags: .net, iis, authentication

My.Net Core application suddenly start prompting for username and password on the browser instead of displaying the web page.  I am not sure exactly what caused this.  The application has always run without a problem and I did not change anything.  Any ideas why the application is now prompting for username and password for localhost:5000?

Even when I enter my windows username and password, the login prompt never goes away.  Suggestions to fixing this will be appreciated

Comment: `localhost:5000`? Did you run it directly at command line via `dotnet run`?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this question.  I found out it was a database issue, and now fixed.. Thank you.

Comment: Either you delete this question, or post your findings as an answer and accept it.